# Python: Xcode no longer allows pip install mysql-python. Workaround Needed

Tags: python, django, xcode

I'm having major issues this morning trying to install mysql-python connector on the Mac.

The issues is down to a recent update to xcode 5.1:

http://bruteforce.gr/installing-mitmproxy-os-x-maverics-bypassing-clang-error-unknown-argument.html

http://forums.getpebble.com/discussion/11862/installation-error-perhaps-due-to-xcode-5-1

However, I have tried the current work-around and I still get the error:

This is what I have tried:

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future sudo pip install mysql-python
```

This is the error:

```
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Anyone had the same issue and know of a workaround that works in your virtual env?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote the post on your first link. I am not 100% percent sure but I think the problem lies with the use of sudo. The variable is set under your user, while the pip command is elevated to root privileges, i.e. is executed under another user. Try to do the above logged in as root user from the start, without sudoing.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thanks for this answer and the article! Because of this issues tho I also found pymysql! So easy to setup I just added pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb() to my settings and I did not need the other connector!